# large yaml loading causing MemoryError

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, out-of-memory, pickle

I have a 350MB yaml file,which I'm trying to load. My laptop seems can't handle it.

**Any suggestion or trick how to load such large file? **

```
import yaml
import yamlloader
import pickle 

_yml_file = os.path.join(cur_dir, "example.yml")
with open(_yml_file, 'r') as yml_file:
    yf = yaml.load(yml_file, Loader = yamlloader.ordereddict.CLoader)
    f = open("example.pkl", 'wb')
    pickle.dump(yf, f, -1)
```

Comment: What do you need the YAML data for? Do you actually need the entire data set to be in the memory at the same time?

Comment: I'm starting with yaml file. As loading yaml to memory takes long, I'm converting it into pkl. Is there a way you can selectively load yaml?